# stop hashing operation using filestream

Tags: c#, multithreading, hash, md5, filestream

I'm having this piece of code that computes the MD5 hash for a given input file.

```
    public static String ComputeMD5(String filename)
    {
        using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
        {
            try
            {
                using (var stream = File.OpenRead(filename))
                {
                    return BitConverter.ToString(md5.ComputeHash(stream)).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // File is not accessible, return String.Empty
                return String.Empty;
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm running this time consuming operation in a separate thread. For very big files this operation may take some seconds/minutes. What I want to do is to be able to stop the operation from another thread, for example using a "Stop" button in the GUI. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read file parts and apply [MD5.TransformBlock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm.transformblock%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to each read part. (Notice, that last part should be read with [MD5.TransformFinalBlock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm.transformfinalblock(v=vs.110).aspx)).
Between processing each block you can check if cancellation is required, you are free to use any synchronization primitives you like.

Here is example, that uses `CancellationToken`:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace Stack
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource())
            {
                var thread = new Thread(() =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var hash = CalcHash("D:/Image.iso", cancellationTokenSource.Token);
                        Console.WriteLine($"Done: hash is {BitConverter.ToString(hash)}");
                    }
                    catch (OperationCanceledException)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Canceled :(");
                    }
                });
                // Start background thread
                thread.Start();

                Console.WriteLine("Working, press any key to exit");
                Console.ReadLine();
                cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Finished");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static byte[] CalcHash(string path, CancellationToken ct)
        {
            using (var stream = File.OpenRead(path))
            using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
            {
                const int blockSize = 1024 * 1024 * 4;
                var buffer = new byte[blockSize];
                long offset = 0;

                while (true)
                {
                    ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                    var read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, blockSize);
                    if (stream.Position == stream.Length)
                    {
                        md5.TransformFinalBlock(buffer, 0, read);
                        break;
                    }
                    offset += md5.TransformBlock(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, buffer, 0);
                    Console.WriteLine($"Processed {offset * 1.0 / 1024 / 1024} MB so far");
                }

                return md5.Hash;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @a-colomba no problems, did my answer solved your problem? Can you close it?